# Scala : get mixin interfaces at runtime

Tags: scala, reflection, traits, mixing, scala-java-interop

I need to get all the interfaces at runtime from a given Class (all loaded in a ClassLoader).

For instance, if a class has been declared this way :

```
trait B
trait C
trait D    
class A extends B with C with D
```

I want to get this information at runtime : **A depends on B and C and D**.
The java getInterfaces() (or the interfaces() from the clapper library) methods gives only the first dependency, namely: **A depends on B**.

Is there a way to achieve that ?

I guess by reflection but I don't know how ?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the class *a priori*. So I can not call 

    typeOf[A]

What I get is a list of classes built by reading the target/classes and intancitating them with Class.forName, so that I get a list of unknown classes at runtime.

    val classes: List[Class[_] = ... // my list of read classes
    classes.map{c=> c-> ???} // Map with its interfaces

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623498/handy-ways-to-show-linearization-of-a-class) gives the answer:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

trait B
trait C
class A extends B with C

val tpe = typeOf[A]
tpe.baseClasses foreach {s => println(s.fullName)}
  // A, C, B, java.lang.Object, scala.Any
```

It works in the REPL, but when I put the code into a Scala script file and executed it, it didn't any longer:

```
typeOf[A]
  // Compiler error: No TypeTag available for this.A
```

Using `weakTypeTag` instead didn't help either

```
weakTypeTag[A]
  // Runtime error: scala.reflect.internal.FatalError:
  // ThisType(free type $anon) for sym which is not a class
```

I got the same behaviour with Scala 2.10.0, 2.10.1 and 2.11.0-M2.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the _scala-reflect_ dependency (`libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.10.0"`), which is granted in the REPL.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I explicitly added it to the classpath - which `scala.bat` automatically does anyway, if I am not mistaken -  but nothing changed. Moreover, I assume that `import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._` (the import had previously been omitted from my answer) would have failed if the library hadn't been present already.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found with reflection :

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
val mirror = ru.rootMirror
val t = m.staticClass(classString).typeSignature
t.baseClasses
```