# How do you cast super in a Scala trait?

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits

I'm trying to write a method in a trait that's recursive on types, but I'm running into the problem that I can't write the base case in such a way that the compiler is convinced I know what I'm doing.

Here's a gist:

```
trait InheritableBehavior {
  def superClassWithInheritableBehavior: Option[Class[_]] = {
    // reflection and magic (from some library's code)
  }

  def doSomething() {
    if (this.superClassWithInheritableBehavior.isDefined) {
      super.doSomething()
    } else {
      // base case here, which relies on local fields
    }
  }
}
```

The compiler suggests I mark `doSomething()` with `abstract override`, but there is no concrete implementation. Everything is in that one method.

I suppose I could split the trait into two--`BaseInheritableTrait`, which doesn't call `super`, and `DerivedInheritableTrait` which includes the `super` call, but is there any better way to deal with this?

What I'd love to be able to do is `super.asInstanceOf[InheritableTrait].doSomething()`, but that doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the compiler is right when it is convinced that we don't know what we're doing.

I'm not sure what you mean by "there is no concrete implementation."

Normally, `abstract override` means you'll be mixed in with a class that has a concrete implementation.  Otherwise, there would be nothing to invoke.

Possibly, you mean, "I have a class with InheritableTrait, and I want to extend it and mix in InheritableTrait again."  But actually, you can't do that.  Your mix-ins are linearized once.

There was a recent question with a great answer, which I'll try to find for you.  And maybe we can mark this as dupe.

Update: here's [a similar recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500342/inheritance-and-code-reuse-in-stackable-traits) which may help answer or help improve your question.  It includes a fine and thorough answer, though frankly I prefer the other answer which received no love but includes fun code.

Consideration:

> is there any better way to deal with this?

Maybe what you're looking for is a self-type here, where you want to specify that you're mixed-in with something:

```
trait Me { _: Konkret =>
  def run() = concrete()
}
```

Maybe there are different kinds of `Konkret` and you want to determine reflectively what to do?

Or maybe you just want a template method:

```
trait Me {
  def doSomething(): Unit
  def run() = doSomething()
}
```

Comment: What I meant by "no concrete implementation" is that the same method works for the base and any derived classes, so the method that calls super would work as a concrete implementation if the compiler wouldn't insist it say abstract override. I'm going to try two versions of the trait. Not clean, but I think I can make it work.