# When extending a trait within a trait, what does 'super' refer to?

Tags: scala, inner-classes, mixins, super, traits

I want to to extend a trait within a trait, like this:

```
  trait NodeTypes {
    trait Node {
      def allNodesHaveThis: Int
    }
  }

  trait ScrumptiousTypes extends NodeTypes {
    trait Node extends super.Node {
      def scrumptiousness: Int
    }
  }

  trait YummyTypes extends NodeTypes {
    trait Node extends super.Node {
      def yumminess: Int
    }
  }

  object Graph extends NodeTypes with ScrumptiousTypes with YummyTypes {
    case class Node() extends super.Node {
      override def allNodesHaveThis = 1
      override def scrumptiousness = 2  // error: ScrumptiousTypes.Node has been disinherited
      override def yumminess = 3
    }
  }
```

If this works, it would be a nice way of saying “When your `Graph` inherits from `<Whatever>Types`, its `Node` class must provide the methods required by `<Whatever>`.”

But the Scala 2.11.2 compiler says:

```
error: method scrumptiousness overrides nothing
      override def scrumptiousness = 2
                   ^
```

It appears that `YummyTypes.Node` shadows `ScrumptiousTypes.Node`, following the usual way that Scala resolves “diamond” inheritance for methods: by type linearization. As I understand things, that *should* be OK, though, because `YummyTypes.Node` explicitly extends `super.Node`, which, by the same type linearization, should refer to `ScrumptiousTypes`.

What have I misunderstood? Or, what does `super.Node` refer to—and why?

---

If you're wondering why I'm doing this, it's so I can mix changes into several traits at once, so the inherited traits interoperate, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33965799/1393162). In the final Node class (and other classes that it works with), I don't want to explicitly extend from each Node trait: I want to mix in from one "thing" (whatever it is) and get all the mutually consistent changes made to Node and the other traits, all in a bundle. Or, if one trait defines a bunch of extensions to Node, extending from ScrumptiousTypes should make all of the Node-extensions contain a `scrumptiousness` member, without having to list all the Node-extensions: `trait Hypernode extends ScrumptiousTypes.Node`, `trait ZealousNode extends ScrumptiousTypes.Node`, etc.

Comment: YummyTypes extends ScrumptiousTypes will fix the issue.

Comment: @ravindra Interesting idea, but I'd prefer not to do that. The idea is that you should be able to mix in the `...Types` traits in any combination that you like. For example, you should be able to require `yumminess` without also requiring `scrumptiousness`, like this: `object Graph extends YummyTypes`.

Answer (score 5):

use type also fix the issue

```
trait NodeTypes {

  trait Node {
    def allNodesHaveThis: Int
  }

}

trait ScrumptiousTypes extends NodeTypes {

  trait Node extends super.Node {
    def scrumptiousness: Int
  }

  type ScrumptiousTypesNode = this.Node
}

trait YummyTypes extends NodeTypes {

  trait Node extends super.Node {
    def yumminess: Int
  }

  type YummyTypesNode = this.Node
}

object Graph extends NodeTypes with ScrumptiousTypes with YummyTypes {

  case class Node() extends ScrumptiousTypesNode with YummyTypesNode {
    override def allNodesHaveThis = 1

    override def scrumptiousness = 2

    override def yumminess = 3
  }

}
```

------v2-------
use object contain to Node ,
but since path depend it is not a good idea ,
and maybe It will be problems

```
trait NodeTypes {

  trait Node {
    def allNodesHaveThis: Int
  }

}

object NodeTypes extends NodeTypes

trait ScrumptiousTypes extends NodeTypes {

  trait Node {
    def scrumptiousness: Int
  }

  type ScrumptiousTypesNode = this.Node
}

object ScrumptiousTypes extends ScrumptiousTypes

trait YummyTypes extends NodeTypes {

  trait Node {
    def yumminess: Int
  }

  type YummyTypesNode = this.Node
}

object YummyTypes extends YummyTypes

trait Nodes {

  trait Nodes extends NodeTypes.Node with  YummyTypes.Node with ScrumptiousTypes.Node

}


object Graph extends  Nodes {

  case class Nodes() extends super.Nodes {
    override def yumminess: Int = 1
//
    override def scrumptiousness: Int = 2

    override def allNodesHaveThis: Int = 3
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using an approach like this right now. It's error-prone, though, because you have to say almost the same thing twice. How could I make it so that inheriting from the `...Types` traits would redefine `Node` (inside the `Graph` object)?

Comment: look at version2 but i do not recommended use it , use type is better  usually,i think

Comment: I posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33965799/1393162) about this, explicitly asking for a workaround. Hopefully that makes clearer what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of class lineraization. See [Spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#class-linearization).

**Explanation**

Let C be a class with template `C1 with ... with Cn`. Then lineraization is concatenation of elements from Cn to C1, replacing all identical elements to left. Here elements include var, val, def, traits, object.

If you want to see the [order of linearization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15624570/757071), use

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
val tpe = typeOf[scala.collection.immutable.List[_]]
tpe.baseClasses foreach { s => println(s.fullName) }
```

In your case, if you change the order from `ScrumptiousTypes with YummyTypes` to `YummyTypes with ScrumptiousTypes`, then error will be on method `yumminess`.

An alternate to @余杰水 is to extend inner class like,

```
case class Node() extends super[ScrumptiousTypes].Node with super[YummyTypes].Node
```

Comment: Thanks—i didn't know about the `super[_traitname_]` syntax. But why doesn't `super.Node` inside `YummyTypes` refer to `ScrumptiousTypes.Node` in `object Graph extends ScrumptiousTypes with YummyTypes`? As I understand linearization (perhaps wrongly), that's how it normally works.

Comment: Indeed! But why? When referring to a var, val, or def, `super` refers to the actual superclass when the trait is mixed into a real object, not to the superclass mentioned in the trait's definition.

Comment: The behavior is mentioned in the spec. I have linked it.

Comment: I just posted the details of my reading of the spec [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33859618/1393162). If you have enough time to read through it, please see if you can tell where I went wrong. Maybe there's some relevant part of the spec that I overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't meant to be an answer. It's just quotations from and interpretations of the spec, which are too long to fit readably into comments (prompted by [johny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33842030/1393162)). I'm spelling out my interpretations so you might be able to spot where I went wrong. Maybe this will lead to an explanation or to a way to chain extensions of traits within traits (or to a bug report in the unlikely event that my interpretation turns out to be right).

### Relevant passages from the Scala spec

> [§6.5 This and Super](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#this-and-super): A reference **super**.*m* refers statically to a method or type *m* in the least proper supertype of the innermost template containing the reference. It evaluates to the member *m′* in the actual supertype of that template which is equal to *m* or which overrides *m.*

The big question is: What does the spec say that `super.Node` inside `YummyTypes` refers to? To find out, we'll need to know the definitions of the spec-specific terms used above:

> [§5.1 Templates](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#templates): A *template* defines the type signature, behavior and initial state of a trait or class of objects or of a single object.

So, a template is what we'd ordinarily call an object, class, or trait definition.

> [§5.4 Traits](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#traits): A *trait* is a class that is meant to be added to some other class as a mixin. … The *least proper supertype* of a template is the class type or compound type consisting of all its parent class types.
>
> [§5.1.2 Class Linearization](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#class-linearization): Let *C* be a class with template *C*<sub>1</sub> `with ... with` *C*<sub>*n*</sub>. The *linearization* of *C*, *L*(*C*), is defined as follows:
>
>      *L*(*C*) = *C,L*(*C*<sub>*n*</sub>) +⃗ … +⃗ *L*(*C*<sub>1</sub>)
>
> Here +⃗ denotes concatenation where elements of the right operand replace identical elements of the left operand.

I take this to mean that the linearization is a sequence of classes, which you get by starting with the class being defined and then reading the **with** types from right to left. When two classes in the linearization define a member or type with the same name (an “element”), the class that comes first “wins”.

So, the linearization of `Graph` should be `Graph`,`YummyTypes`,`ScrumptiousTypes`,`NodeTypes`, followed by standard stuff like `Any`. Indeed, this is confirmed when I modify `Graph` like this:

```
  object Graph extends ScrumptiousTypes with YummyTypes {
    case class Node() extends super.Node { /* … */ }

    typeOf[Graph.type].baseClasses foreach { s => println(s.fullName) }
  }
```

which produces:

```
Graph
YummyTypes
ScrumptiousTypes
NodeTypes
java.lang.Object
scala.Any
```

> [§5.4 Traits](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#traits): Assume a trait *D* defines some aspect of an instance *x* of type *C* (i.e. *D* is a base class of *C*). Then the *actual supertype* of *D* in *x* is the compound type consisting of all the base classes in *L*(*C*) that succeed *D.* The actual supertype gives the context for resolving a super reference in a trait. Note that the actual supertype depends on the type to which the trait is added in a mixin composition; it is not statically known at the time the trait is defined.

I take this to mean that the "actual" least proper supertype of a mixed-in trait is determined by the type of the actual object that the trait is mixed into (`Graph` in my example), not necessarily a supertype that the trait's definition explicitly extends (`NodeTypes` in my example).

### Conclusion

So, it would appear that the actual supertype of `YummyTypes` in `Graph` should be `ScrumptiousTypes`. And so, the actual supertype of `YummyTypes.Node` in `Graph` should be `ScrumptiousTypes.Node`.

However, adding this line to `Graph`:

```
typeOf[Node].baseClasses foreach { s => println(s.fullName) }
```

produces:

```
Graph.Node
scala.Serializable
java.io.Serializable
scala.Product
scala.Equals
YummyTypes.Node
NodeTypes.Node
java.lang.Object
scala.Any
```

`ScrumptiousTypes.Node` is missing. Apparently, inside `YummyTypes`, `super.Node` does not refer to `Node` in `YummyTypes`' actual least proper supertype.

However, if I add:

```
abstract override def text = super.text + " ScrumptiousTypes" // in ScrumptiousTypes 
abstract override def text = super.text + " YummyTypes"       // in YummyTypes
```

printing `text` in `Graph` produces:

```
 ScrumptiousTypes YummyTypes
```

demonstrating that inside `YummyTypes` in `Graph`, `super.text` *does* refer to `ScrumptiousTypes.text`!

Comment: great research here -- wondering if this is really better suited as an addition to the original question? (or perhaps a new question)

Comment: @ImranRashid I was afraid it would make the question so long that no one would want to read it. However, over the past week, my concern has shifted from "what's going on here?" to "is this a compiler bug or not?" I'll think about it. :)